# saveas white border matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, removing-whitespace, save-as

I want to save a frame as an image in png format with saveas command. Although my image's size is 640X480 (gcf), the saved images size is 1201x901 and spaces white color.(like a bold white border).So I want the image to be saved 640x480.
I tried transparent background but it didn't work. How can I fix this problem?

```
F(j) = getframe(gcf);
fname='C:\...'
saveas(gcf, fullfile(fname, 'newImage'), 'png');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
set(gca,'position',[0 0 1 1],'units','normalized')
```

or you can try the `imcrop`function.

Answer (score 0):

If you aren't overlaying any graphics over the image, then save the image data directly using `imwrite`, rather than exporting a figure containing the image to png.

If you are overlaying graphics then the [export_fig](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/matlabcentral/fileexchange/23629-exportfig) function (available for download on the MATLAB File Exchange) will automatically crop the whitespace around the figure. In this case use:

```
export_fig(fullfile(fname, 'newImage'), '-png', '-a1', '-native');
```